# TSQL - use variables in OPENXML

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have a query like this -

```
SELECT * FROM 
    OPENXML(@i, '/root/authors', 2) 
        WITH authors
```

Now, I want to pass `'/root'` via a parameter/variable like -

```
DECLARE @nodeName varchar(MAX) ----> EDIT: Solution- Use fixed length instead of MAX
SET @nodeName = '/root'
```

and use @nodeName instead. Then concatenate the rest of the elements dynamically. 
I am getting error just by using @nodeName in the OPENXML parameter.

Comment: Can we see the actual code and the error message?

Comment: That is the code sample from msdn using the PUBS DB. OPENXML(@i, @nodeName, 2)

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: The parameters supplied for the function "OpenXML" are not valid. But, if I remove the variable and replace with the '/root', it works

Comment: Need to see /YOUR/ code, not MSDN code. As much as you are comfortable displaying publicly.

Comment: I have edited with solution. Now going to the 2nd part of the question. How do I concatenate dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following in SQL 2008 R2 and it works fine.

```
DECLARE @idoc int
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)
SET @doc ='
<ROOT>
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">
   <Order CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">
   <Order CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
</ROOT>'
--Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc
-- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.
DECLARE @NodeName VARCHAR(100)
SET @NodeName = '/ROOT/Customer'
SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, @NodeName,1)
            WITH (CustomerID  varchar(10),
                  ContactName varchar(20))
```

It could be that other versions of SQL only support the use of NVARCHAR as a parameter, not VARCHAR.

I hope this help.

Comment: I got the issue. In the DECLARE @NodeName part, I cannot use MAX. I should pass a fixed length like varchar(50). Then it works !

Comment: I have edited with solution. Now going to the 2nd part of the question. How do I concatenate dynamically ?

Answer (score 2):

Better to use the new XML type.

```
create proc [dbo].[getLocationTypes](@locationIds XML,
@typeIds XML=null)
as  
begin  
set nocount on  


SELECT locationId, typeId
FROM xrefLocationTypes 
WHERE locationId 
IN (SELECT Item.value('.', 'int' )
FROM @locationIDs.nodes('IDList/ID') AS x(Item))
AND (typeId IN
 (SELECT Item.value('.', 'int' )
FROM @typeIds.nodes('IDList/ID') AS x(Item)))
ORDER BY 1, 2

end
```

And then you would call this like:

```
EXECUTE dbo.getLocationTypes '<IDList><ID>1</ID><ID>3</ID></IDList>', 
'<IDList><ID>200</ID><ID>300</ID><ID>400</ID></IDList>'
```